# Is this code the right way to prevent duplicate IDs?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, duplicates

I have this code below that supposedly will detect duplicate id generation and will not execute.  Is this code good enough to prevent duplicate ids?

```
 //$guid and $alphabet are other sources from which id is generated
 $unique = false;
 while($unique == false){
     $Guid = NewGuid();
     ob_start();
     echo base_encode($Guid, $alphabet); 
     $newid = ob_get_contents();
     ob_get_clean();

     $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='$newid'";
     $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) 
         $unique = true;
 }
```

Comment: No, it's racy. what is `NewGuid()`? If you generate a globally unique identifier, chances are very very small that it is non-unique.

Comment: Why on earth is it echoed to the ouput buffer and read back in to `$newid`!??

Comment: You're approaching the problem from the wrong angle.  The database can generate an ID for you if you set your primary key to autoincrement, Why not just do that?

Comment: @gordonm that will just be numbers i need 5 alphanumeric passcodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach would be to allow MySQL to create the IDs using auto_increment.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
   id int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   /* other columns... */
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Then you just insert without specifying the ID column. To retrieve the value, use `mysql_insert_id()`.

If there is some valid reason you can't use auto_increment (you have no control over the database and have been told no at least a hundred times by at least 10 IT people), then the next solution would be to add a unique index on the column, which would prevent entering a duplicate.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name (id);
```

This will prevent any duplicates. If an attempt to insert fails because of a unique key being violated (which will be in the error message), you can simply retry the insert with a new GUID.

Collisions will be rare enough (near impossible) that you don't really have to worry about optimizing this unless there will be tens of millions of records (probably hundreds of millions).

There aren't going to be many other good options that can avoid a race condition. You can manage it with transactions, but it's going to be very, very tricky at your current level of understanding and in almost all cases a waste of your time given these two options above.

So I guess to summarize, the specific answer to the question you posited is probably to just try and insert it. If you get a dup, ask for a new ID and try again. But there are probably better strategies depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

php has a function to generate unique id's eg. uniqid

Relying on the auto-increment of the DB violates command-query responsibility segregation and can lead to issue when building large applications.

Comment: The effect on "large applications" is an interesting point of design that should be considered. I wouldn't go as far as to make it a blanket statement, though. If you're going to suggest `uniqid` then there should at least be some mention of the many caveats of `prefix` and `more_entropy`, which are crucial to creating an actually unique ID. Also, the question was how to prevent duplicates; uniqid does not guarantee there will never be duplicates, even with `more_entropy` applied, and the question remains unanswered...